# golang flag hidden options from print defaults

Tags: go

this is my actual code :

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
)

var loadList  = "" 
var threads   = 50
var skip      = 0


func main() {

    //defaults variables
    flag.StringVar(&loadList, "f", "", "load links list file (required)") 
    flag.IntVar(&threads,"t", 50, "run `N` attempts in parallel threads")
    flag.IntVar(&skip, "l", 0, "skip first `n` lines of input")
    flag.Parse()

    flag.PrintDefaults()

}
```

and this is output :

-f string
        load links list file (required)
  -l n
        skip first n lines of input
  -t N
        run N attempts in parallel threads (default 50)

i want hide from printdefaults -l and -t, how i can do this ?

Answer (score 1):

There might be multiple ways of doing this. An easy one would be to use [`VisitAll`](https://golang.org/pkg/flag/#VisitAll):

```
func VisitAll(fn func(*Flag))
```

In the function you pass you can decide whether or not to output a flag based on any of the exported fields of `Flag`.

---

Example:

```
flag.VisitAll(func(f *flag.Flag) {
    if f.Name == "l" || f.Name == "t" {
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("Flag: ", f)
})
```

Run it at: https://play.golang.org/p/rsrKgWeAQf

Comment: @StefanoConte I added a tiny example.

Comment: is total diferent, i want this output :  " -f string
        load links list file (required)"